# Using labels in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a `<label>` to show some text on a JQuery UI Dialog object.  But it always seems to lose the value.  Here is the code snippet where I am setting the value :

```
function populateDialog(intMeterID) {

                  $.ajax(
                   {
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/WS.asmx/GetMeterSettingsByMeterID",
                       data: "{intMeterID:" + intMeterID + "}",
                       async: false,
                       dataType: "json",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                       success: function(msg) {

                           var strMeterName = msg.d.MeterName;

                           $("label[for='lblMeterID']").text(intMeterID);
                           $("label[for='lblMeterName']").text(strMeterName);
```

And on a button click I am then trying to take the value from the label, but it is empty.  However, the msg.d.MeterName does contain the data!

```
function saveMeterDetails() {

                   var intMeterID = $("label[for='lblMeterID']").text();
                   var strMeterName = $("label[for='lblMeterName']").text();
```

html:

```
<div id="dialog-form">
    <div style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;" id="dialog">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label style="display:none;" for="lblMeterID" />
                    <label style="font-weight:bold;" for="lblMeterName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            [...]
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: you should also post the corresponding HTML form to facilitate debug...

Comment: try using `value()` instead of `text()` ?

Comment: This is my HTML :  <div id="dialog-form">
        <div style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;" id="dialog">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>    
                        <label style="display:none;" for="lblMeterID" />
                        <label style="font-weight:bold;" for="lblMeterName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>

Comment: The strange thing is, the Meter Name is displayed, but only when I remove the line before where I set it :$("label[for='lblMeterID']").text(intMeterID);

Comment: I found the answer, though I don't know why it works.  I took the Meter ID label into a row on it's own, like this : <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label style="display:none;" for="lblMeterID" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>   
                        <label style="font-weight:bold;" for="lblMeterName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a scope issue. When the success callback is called 'intMeterID' doesn't really exist in that scope. Even though you pass it during the initial call. You need to make it a global variable, or pass it back as data from the ajax call.

The code works now because you removed the erroneous call that sets an undefined text to the label.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has actually nothing to do with label itself. I think intMeterID is empty at the time of the 'success' callback. That's why it does work if you remove that line.

What you are actually doing with 'success: function() {blah}' is defining a new function that will be called whenever the request is succesfull. At that time 'intMeterID' is unknown.

You could perhaps make it a global variable if you really need it, or make the ajax call blocking or (my favorite) add the variable server-side to your ajax results.

Edit: hm, nevermind, I just read you already found your answer. Apparantly I was wrong :)

Comment: no actually I think you were right ;-) , intMeterID is undefined and breaks the remaining of the function